# Getting too much gap between two component react native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

am new in react world, am trying to making a d-mart clone, my app is working fine but getting too much difference between two banner component , I don't want it , don't know why its getting. please try to fix my error.

[image]

You seem in special offer top and bottom difference is good but winter special top getting too much difference.

> App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Header from "./screens/Header";
import Banner from "./screens/Banner";
import Banner2 from "./screens/Banner2";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Header />
        <Banner />
        <Banner2 name="Special Offer"/>
        <Banner2 name="Winter Special"/>
        <Banner2 name="New Year Special"/>
        <Banner2 name="Festival Special"/>
      </ScrollView>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Banner2.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const Banner2 = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 7 }}>
      <Text style={styles.offer}>{name}</Text>
      <Image
        style={{
          height: 300,
          width: "100%",
          marginTop: -30,
          alignItems: "center",
          resizeMode: "contain",
        }}
        source={require("../images/banner1.jpg")}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  offer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 20,
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
});

export default Banner2;
```

Comment: removing `marginTop: 20,` may help you

Comment: try to use margin vertical for each banner